# Compound brute force/evolutionary engine search in Ruby

Tags: ruby, computer-science

A question with regards to a subject I have been thinking about. Is it possible to utilize a compound process in either a brute force search or evolutionary programming? I am working on this myself at the moment though it is proving quite difficult.

The premise is that it should be possible to utilize a compound process somewhat similar to the way compound interest is determined in normal savings accounts.

I have been trying to implement a evolutionary algorithmim in the following way.

A has the ability to spawn new systems and has a 'spawning' fitness of 5.0 (IE the systems that it spawns are 5 times as effective as A itself) - if A spawns B and then B spawns C, the fitness of the systems (organisims) should compound as such

A = 5.0

B = 5.0 * A = 25.0

C = 25.0 * B = 625.0

Can anyone assist with implementing this heurisitic in code? (Ruby or Psudocode)

What I have at the moment is something like this

I have a class called system, that has a method that generates a random number, I want to evolve new systems that are better able to generate a random number that matches a second generated random number. The systems that successfuly match the second generated random number with their 'predictions' (the first random number) will have their score increased, the ones that are unsuccessful will have their score decreased.

The systems then spawn 'child' systems, which are also tested in the manner just mentioned, though here we utilize the fitness of the child systems as the 'spawning' fitness of the spawning systems. This allows me to know which 'systems' spawn successful systems.

Though I can easily determine which systems are the best at spawning systems that can predict the randomly generated number, I am unsure as to how I can assess the spawning systems for their ability to spawn systems (that spawn systems) and since this chain continues I believe that the determiniation of fitness may be recursive.

Finally, since the ultimate detemination of the 'fitness' of a system would be dependant on the predictive ability of the systems generated, how does the compounding of 'spawning' fitness factor into the equation?

Also, if I evolve a PRNG that matches the PRNG that ruby uses, the PRNG would incrementally evolve to match the PRNG in ruby's underlying algorthim. Please not this, At time 1, we have 1 piece of information from the PRNG we are trying to predict, this provides us with a 1/1 or 100% model at that timestep. If we then retrieve a second piece of information at timestep two we have 100% more information at time step two than we did before timestep two, therefor the prediction ability should thus be 200% (100% at timestep two with 0 extra information, 100% extra information at timestep two,leaving twice the predictive ability of the original system.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question and I would be very grateful if you could assist in any way.

Let me know if you have any questions

Thanks in advance

Regards

Martin

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do in terms of inputs/outputs of the algorithm.  What is the dataset you are working with?  What does a successful search mean?

Comment: The dataset is currenty simply the built in random number generator in ruby, I would be attempting to brute force a random number generator that is 'in sync' with the number generator that I am attempting to predict, IE it generates the same number as the random number generator (this is a toy POC problem, similar to the travelling salesman problem). A successful search would result in a random number genarator that would produce the same value as the number generator that I am trying to predict. Cheers, Martin

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this with a search algorithm because you have no way of knowing how "close" you are to matching the random-number generating algorithm.  A value that is close to the random number is more likely to be by coincidence than actually proving you are getting closer to the underlying algorithm.

If you are doing this as a toy project, use a dataset that you can create a fitness function for (if evolutionary programming).  Common data sets are spam detection, image recognition, user preferences, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Garrett, but I was hoping you could clarify how I would compound my evolutionary search - specifically how I would implement a 'spawning' function correcty since the only gauge I would have at how good the evolved system is at prediction is its 'prediction' fitness. To summerise, how can I include a compound process in an evolutionary search. Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Please see my editied question for something further, its too large for the comment box

Comment: Each generation you should eliminate the least fit from the population, combine ("mate") the most fit, and add some randomization ("mutation").  Again, I think you are going to have difficulty converging on a random number generator.

Comment: Will simply utilizing recombination,mutation and sex facilitate a compounding in fitness? I'm not saying that converging upon a PRNG won't be difficult but I do have float's with percentage scores so I can see just how well the system is at predicting the PRNG

Comment: Evolutionary algorithms do not necessarily converge because you can have cyclic dominance in strategies (A > B > C > A).  You could look at simulated annealing as an alternative.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean convergance as compounding? I am wanting to compound the fitness of the organsims, I assume you understand what I mean by 'compounding', is this the same as simulated annealing? IE does simulated annealing produce systems that compound in fitness, also why would a cyclically dominante stratagy be unwanted? If it has the highest fitness then I would assume that that would be all that is pertinate. If you can clarify that would be great, thanks, Martin

Comment: Can anyone comment as to whether normal evolutionary algorithms (including mutation and recombination) will provide compound increases in fitness? Cheers Martin